# Notice: Undefined offset procurando dentro de array com for

Tags: php, mysql

Olá!

Meu código é uma agenda e funciona da seguinte forma, existe uma array com alguns horários dentro:

```
$horarios = ["08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00"];
```

Faço então um SELECT no banco procurando por agendamentos e armazeno os dados dentro de uma array através de um foreach:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT *, date_format(hora_agendamento, '%H%:%i') as hora_agendamento FROM agendamentos WHERE data_agendamento='$data_agendamento_convert' AND medico='$medico_completo'");
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Após isso através de um for eu ando dentro da array e verifico se cada horário da array $horarios pode ser encontrado dentro da array $result:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= (count($horarios) - 1); $i++) {
  if (in_array($horarios[$i], $result[$i])) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result[$i]['nome']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result[$i]['descricao']; ?></td>
      <td>Editar</td>
    </tr>
 <?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>Editar</td>
     </tr>
 <?php } }?>
```

A primeira linha encontrada é impressa corretamente, depois acredito que pelo fato de ter 10 horários em $horarios e apenas 3 matches em $result o código começa a me retornar o erro abaixo:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp64\www\admin\agenda1.php on line 91

Imagino que se eu melhorar esse meu if eu consiga resolver o problema, mas nâo estou sabendo o que usar pra melhorar ele, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Obrigado!

Comment: Se código pode conter problemas inclusive na elaboração, porque, fetchAll() não já te retornar um array ? para fazer um for? qual é a linha 96?

Comment: Sim, retorna, mas eu preciso usar esses dados fora do foreach, por isso alimentei outra array com os dados que o SELECT retorna. Linha 96: if (in_array($horarios[$i], $agendamentos[$i])) { ?>

Comment: Não precisa gerar os dados se você tem os dados!? compreende isso. a variavel result é a mesma coisa que a variavel agendamentos

Comment: Nossa, corretíssimo, falha minha haha, porém o problema do Undefined offset persiste, porque o conteúdo das duas arrays(agendamentos e result) são o mesmo.

Comment: Aqui o próximo problema: `if (in_array($horarios[$i], $result[$i])) { ?>` porque o `result[$i]` você está acessando o registro e não o array que precisa, se você precisar comparar horários tem que ter outra estratégia. Qual é a finalidade dessa parte?

Comment: Nessa parte quero saber se há agendamentos para os horários contidos na array $horarios, assim fiz uma condição para quando for encontrado registro igual ele mostrar pra mim na tabela os dados daquele agendamento, nome do paciente e descrição do agendamento, caso não encontre nada ele executa o else e completa a tabela com dados em branco.

Comment: Bom vamos lá! pra que saber o resultado se a SQL traz o que tem? não é só imprimir `$result`? pra que comparar se precisa mostrar ? pensa um pouco! dica tira essa verificação e manda imprimir na tela!

Comment: Desta forma ele imprime as linhas certinho uma após a outra, porém preciso agora que ele verifique o horário do agendamento e preencha a linha correta, por isso havia aquele if, pra quando der match entre o horário da $horarios e o horário da $result ele preencher aquela linha com os dados, quando não desse match, executava o else e preenchia a linha em branco, assim eu tinha vista da agenda com todos os horários usados e os disponíveis também, essa é a ideia.

Comment: Então faz assim: `if (in_array($result[$i]['hora_agendamento'], $horarios)) { ?>` ou seja, é só inverter as variaveis dentro da função `in_array`

Comment: Tá pegando os dados, só continua dando undefined offset 3, porque tem poucos resultados, vai de 0 a 2 só(3 registros encontrados no banco), preciso parar de iterar $result porque em dado momento ocorre de eu estar querendo dados de um offset inexistente dentro da array e gera o erro, preciso de um if melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz isso:

```
if (isset($result[$i]) && in_array($result[$i], $horarios)) { ?>
```

Assim esse erro irá parar de aparecer pois o `isset($result[$i])` verifica se EXISTE a variável com o índice dentro array `$result`. Que retornará `true` caso exista e desde que esse valor não seja nulo.

```
$array = array(0 => "oi", 1 => "", 2 => null, 3 => false);

isset( $array [0] ) // true
isset( $array [1] ) // true
isset( $array [2] ) // false
isset( $array [3] ) // true
```

Além disso, conforme citado pelo **Virgilio Novic**  nos comentários, o certo é:

```
in_array ("valor que eu procuro", array());
```

**[Veja a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)**

Portanto, você precisa colocar o `$result[$i]` antes de `$horarios`. Como `$horarios` já é um array(), você não precisa indicar um índice em `$horarios`.

**EDIT**

Conforme a imagem mostrada, você pode fazer um loop dentro do seu loop, para analisar cada caso. Veja:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($horarios); $i++){
    $status = true;
    foreach($result as $resultado){
        if($horarios[$i] == $resultado['hora_agendamento']){
        ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $resultado['nome']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $resultado['descricao']; ?></td>
              <td>Editar</td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
            $status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($status){ ?>

    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>Editar</td>
     </tr>

<?php }}?>
```

**EDIT 2**

Apesar da outra forma atender, este exemplo abaixo, com `array_search` é mais otimizado.

```
$horariosCheios = array();
foreach($result as $resultado){
    $horariosCheios[] = $resultado['hora_agendamento'];
}

for ($i=0; $i <= (count($horarios) - 1); $i++) {
  if (($indice = array_search($horarios[$i], $horariosCheios)) !== false) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result[$indice]['nome']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result[$indice]['descricao']; ?></td>
      <td>Editar</td>
    </tr>
 <?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $horarios[$i]; ?></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>Editar</td>
     </tr>
 <?php } }?>
```

Comment: Compreendo, porém surge um problema, se com o if eu procurar o conteúdo de $result dentro de $horarios vai acabar exibindo pra mim primeiro os 3 resultados encontrados, depois os que caíram no else, como se vê na imagem abaixo, vou pensar em algo pra contornar: https://imgur.com/a/xCCIvrN

Comment: @FernandoGross tente agora.

Comment: Show de bola, não podia ter dado mais certo, estava fazendo algo do gênero mas meio cético, sou sempre receoso pra acumular muitos loops, mas funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado, além do código peguei dicas valiosas, tanto suas @Andrei Coelho quanto do Virgilio Novic.

Comment: @FernandoGross eu dei essa sugestão mas ela não deve ser a melhor. Isso é só um exemplo, pois dependendo da quantidade você irá fazer muitos loops desnecessários talvez. Você precisa depois refatorar esse código e fazer uns testes. Pesquise também sobre array_search. Poderá te ajudar mais. Abraço!

Comment: @FernandoGross coloquei no edit 2 um exemplo melhor.

Comment: Ótimo! Quando eu estava procurando por qual função utilizar pra procurar os horários dentro da array eu esbarrei nessa função lá na documentação, mas não cheguei a testar ela, o princípio é bem parecido.

Comment: @FernandoGross sim. E fica mais parecido com o que você fez no seu primeiro código.